# Does SDWebImage support "not-when-fast-scrolling" (skimming) for lazy loading?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, lazy-loading, sdwebimage

When doing lazy loading (table of UICollectionView),

for a correct result, you should NOT begin downloads, when the user is scrolling very quickly over the collection.

So, imagine a vertical scroll with 200 panels each with an image; four or five are seen onscreen at a time.

When it first loads, the first 4 visible images should begin loading.  If you scroll down a little, the newly visible images should begin to load.

BUT if the user: very quickly scrolls down to (say) position 100 and then positions the view showing items 100-104 ... you ideally SHOULD NOT starting loading the images which the user "skimmed" over very quickly (say, 4 through 99), you should only kick in the downloads when the user stops scrolling very quickly, and apparently is stopping or slowing on some images.

So, this is a standard thing you have to do in any high-quality lazy-loading scroll. You don't start loading when the user is skimming.

My question is simply: does SDWebImage support this concept?  If not is there another popular ready-made approach?  Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't support it, because it's usually a category on an image view, but it would be pretty straightforward to add the ability yourself.

Assuming you were kicking off the image load in `cellForItem...`, you'd add a dispatch after block which would only kick off the load if the same cell still had the same index path after, say, 0.2 seconds.

I'd check if you had a measurable problem before doing anything, though - AFAIK SDWebImage (and definitely the AFNetworking image view category) will cancel any outstanding URL requests when a new one is received, so you might be making an unnecessary optimisation.

Comment: hi JR thanks for the confirmation it is not built-in to SD !!  cheers

Comment: Hey JR - you know, that's a great idea about "just waiting"; we've always done it the "other way" by checking if you are still scrolling fast. your idea is more KISS, awesome.  FYI I find about 0.4 is ideal (would depend on the layout involved / size of images / other factors I guess). Thanks again!

Comment: I actually wrote the original answer saying to check scrolling / reload on stopping, then the waiting thing occurred to me. It does seem a lot simpler!

Comment: I can confirm it is incredibly simpler, and in practice works much better. It's true that, in theory, you are 'pointlessly' waiting 0.4 seconds for the first cells which appear, to load -- but, so what?  We have always done it the other way, checking that the cells are showing, scrolling speed etc -- and now I just feel stupid  :/  THANKS AGAIN

Comment: @Joe Blow: could you please give some example code? Thanks

Comment: What time do we need to delay if the number of rows is 4000?
Do we need a effective approach for this?

Comment: @NghiaLuong the number of rows makes no difference.